# how to map dynamic tables created at runtime using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a web application. we are using hibernate as ORM in our project. Actually, our project creates dynamic tables. the problem here is when i create tables using HQL i.e. using,

**createTableQuery = "Create Table F0";
s.createSQLQuery(createTableQuery.toString()).executeUpdate();**

it is being created and when i want to use it in other class then it is generating an **error : F0 is not mapped**. so, i want to know whether there are any techniques or concepts to map the table "F0" dynamically in hibernate.

for example, in my project i had tables like below,

**table1_Column1(pk)    table1_Column2    table1_Column3

F0                                  Fname                     Ftype**

**table2_Column1(FK)   table2_Column2(PK)    table2_Column3

F0                                  FF0                                 FFname

F0                                  FF1                                FFname1**

now i have to create dynamic tables using hibernate and the table should look like this,

tablename = **F0**

column -> **FF0            FF1**

value     -> **FFname    FFname1**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, do you get answer of you question? I am in the same situation.